# Android Alarm not differentiate in AM And PM

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing multi time Android Alarm app but in first step i have problem is that its not differentiate in AM and PM i don't know what is wrong in my code. below is my MainActivity Class code in which i have problem i am getting time for alarm from time-picker.

```
Button start;
TimePicker timeP;
TextView tv;
EditText et;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    timeP = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tex);

    // tv.setText(""+System.currentTimeMillis()+20000);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String messg = et.getText().toString();

            Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

            time.set(Calendar.HOUR, timeP.getCurrentHour());
            time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeP.getCurrentMinute());
            //time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            time.set(Calendar.AM_PM, time.PM);


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);

            intent.putExtra("msg", messg);

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
            );}
```

Thanks .

Comment: Why aren't you working on a 24 hour clock?

Comment: its require to working on 12 hour clock to differentiate in AM and PM

Comment: can you tell me how can i use 24 hour clock in alarm but user enter time by using time picker plz

Comment: @hope : You are always setting the time to PM using the following code `time.set(Calendar.AM_PM, time.PM);` - get rid of that line. The `TimePicker` method `getCurrentHour()` always returns a value between 0-23 compensated automatically for whether the picker is using AM/PM or 24 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Instead using 12 hour clock, use 24 hour clock to achieve. Grab your TimePicker time and parse to 24 hour clock check following code:

```
_Strtime="11:30 AM";

SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

mCalendar.setTime(mDateFormat1.parse(_Strtime));


PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```